# Conditional fields with jQuery and Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, html, forms, semantic-ui

I have a form built with semantic-ui and I need to make a few fields appear conditionally, in case a specified selection is made.

Here's the html code:

```
        <div class="field">
          <label>Pay Mode</label>
          <div class="ui selection dropdown" id="paymode">
            <input type='hidden' name='pay_mode'>
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div class="default text">Pay Mode</div>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="item" data-value="free">Free</div>
                <div class="item" data-value="stand alone">Stand alone</div>
                <div class="item" data-value="central system">Central System</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="conditional">
          <div class='three fields'>
            <div class='field'>
              <label>A1</label>
              <input
                type='text'
                name='a1'
                value=''
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div class='field'>
              <label>A2</label>
              <input
                type='text'
                name='a2'
                value=''
                required
              />
           ...
```

So basically, the condition is the Pay Mode. The class "conditional" only has to show up if "Stand alone" is selected at Pay Mode.

Here's my js file:

```
$('.conditional').hide();
$('#paymode').change(function () {
   var selected = $('#paymode item:selected').text();
   $('.conditional').toggle(selected == "Stand alone");
});
```

This successful hides the conditional class, but the same class does not show up even if Stand alone is selected as an option.
What is wrong with this code? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Slightly modify the Pay Mode dropdown field like this:

```
            <div class="field">
              <label>Pay Mode</label>
              <select name="pay_mode" class="ui fluid dropdown" id="condition">
                  <option value="">Pay Mode</option>
                  <option value="free">Free</option>
                  <option value="stand alone">Stand alone</option>
                  <option value="central system">Central System</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

And the js file like this:

```
    $('.conditional').hide();

    $('#condition').change(function () {
      var selected = $('#condition option:selected').text();
      $('.conditional').toggle(selected == "Stand alone");
    });
```

it works like a charm!